# Why my 2nd monitor not working in Ubuntu Xorg

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, xorg, hdmi, wayland

I have 2 monitors connected to my laptop running Ubuntu 21.10. One monitor connected via `hdmi` and the other via a `DisplayLink USB to HDMI adapter`. When in `Wayland`, both work fine, but in `Xorg`, the monitor connected via the `USB adapter` does not work. It is not a big of a deal since I can do my work just fine in `Wayland`, but I am curious why would it not work in `Xorg`.

I have checked if there are any drivers that need to be installed in the `software updater`, but there are none.

If you need any additional information tell me.

Comment: If it is "not a big of a deal since I can do my work just fine in Wayland", why worry about it at all? Xorg is going away ...

Comment: cuz i had some minor troubles with wayland. would have preferred to stay with xorg.

Comment: @matigo can't use Wayland since I can't share screen on it, can't use Xorg because second monitor won't start... 

Comment: @AlexSifuentes this is exactly my problem. I guess there is no straightforward fix for this. There will always be a sacrifice to make.